# Access package accessible constructor outside package

Tags: java, reflection, constructor, illegalaccessexception

I knot that it sound a bit controversial, but I must access a constructor that is protected with the `package` accessor... however I'm outside that package, and so I was using reflection to access that constructor like so:

```
Constructor<TargetClass> constructor = TargetClass.class.getDeclaredConstructor(SomeClass.class);
var manager = constructor.newInstance(new SomeClass());
```

However when I run this, I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class com.mypackage.Application cannot access a member of class com.someotherpackage.TargetClass with modifiers ""
```

Are there ways to avoid this, or either other ways to access that constructor?

Comment: @user15793316 sometimes, for some reason, I forgot that the documentation exists, and people like you should just throw a rock into my head ahahah thank you so much, please consider making an answer, so that i can mark it as correct, and giving you a thumbs up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `setAccessible`.

```
Constructor<TargetClass> constructor =
    TargetClass.class.getDeclaredConstructor(SomeClass.class);
constructor.setAccessible(true);
var manager = constructor.newInstance(new SomeClass());
```

Reflection is almost always being a bad idea. `setAccessible` is worse. Modules may add further complications.